# Using PHP to reorder mysql table after deleting a row?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm coding a CMS table where it allows user to delete data on the front-end.

Below is what being generated:

[image]

If I delete one of the row using

```
mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM registration WHERE number=$deletenumber");
```

It would now look like this

[image]

How do I renumber the number column everytime I delete a row from the table?

Comment: What does "number" semantically mean?  Why do you need to change it?  If it's just supposed to dynamically represent a row count, then it doesn't need to be stored in the first place.  The row count can be determined any time you query the data.

Comment: Please add structure of the table. I agree to David. Column "Number" is the primary key?

Comment: The `DELETE` query you're using implies that `number` is the system identifier for the record.  If that's the case, ***don't*** modify it.  This gets asked often, and I don't know where people get the idea that they should do this.  It has never, ever been a good idea.

Comment: Basically, don't worry about the numbers

Answer (score 1):

```
$Query = "DELETE FROM registration WHERE number=$deletenumber;
          UPDATE registration set number = number-1 WHERE number > $deletenumber";
mysqli_query($conn, $Query);
```

After restore of your table ..

You can make the deletion process with an other query to update all the records that have a number greater than it (it will pull-up all of it one step)

```
UPDATE registration set number = number-1 WHERE number > $deletenumber";
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Code without explanation is considered low quality

Comment: explain the answer.

Comment: Sorry I have added annotation